# Installing Microsoft Office 2016 on SharePoint Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-2016

After I installed a **Microft Office 2016** on ** a SharePoint Server 2016 (Win 2016)**, the central admin had error **503 Service Unavailable**. I opened Windows Service and saw that only one a SharePoint Administrator Service was started and I tried to start SharePoint Timer Service but it didn't start (**Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion"**). Please help me.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, Install **Office 2016 updates** and then Repair the **Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016** from *Control Panel* --> *Programs and Features*

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we faced the same issue after installing MS Office 2016 64bit on SharePoint 2016 application server.
The fix was found in this article: [SharePoint 2016 Forgets Where It’s Installed After Update](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9357/sharepoint-2016-forgets-where-its-installed-after-update).

*If it looks like everything on a SharePoint server suddenly stops working, **make sure the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\16.0\Location points to the right place.***

In our case the value of that key was empty.

I believe simply repairing SharePoint server installation also would help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure All application pool are running in IIS. Sometimes this can happen. If application pool is down you get 503 error message.

Answer (score 0):

I checked that and all applications are started. Everything is ok untill i install office 2016